# Tetrahedron circumradius in high dimensions

Tags: geometry, reference-request, euclidean-geometry, solid-geometry, discrete-geometry

I guess this answer had already been answered a long time ago, but indeed I cannot find any reference.

What is the circumradius of a $n$-dimensional regular hypertetrahedron? Does it approach the length of the hypertetrahedron edges as $n$ increases?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard $n$ simplex is the convex hull in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ of the points $$(1,0,0,\dots,0),\\
(0,1,0,\dots,0)\\
\vdots\\
(0,0,\dots,0,1)$$
That is, the set of all points in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ whose coordinates are nonnegative and add up to $1$.  The edge length is $\sqrt2$ and the center is at $(\frac1{n+1},\frac1{n+1}, \dots,\frac1{n+1})$.  A simple calculation shows that the distance from the center to a vertex approaches $1$ as $n\to\infty,$ so the ratio of the edge length to the circumradius actually goes to $\sqrt2$ as $n\to\infty$.

Thanks to Adam Zalcmann for pointing out the error in my previous calculation.  See his comment below for the detailed calculation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @saulspatz . My question is about $n$-dimensional *regular*  hypertetrahedrons. How can we know if this holds even for them?

Comment: Isn't a hyper-tetrahedron the same thing as a simplex?  In what way is the standard simplex irregular?  There's a cyclic permutation matrix, that is, a rigid motion of the simplex, taking any vertex to any other vertex.  What could be more regular?

Comment: Of course, yes, thank you @saulspatz

Comment: @saulspatz I'm getting that the circumradius approaches $\sqrt{2}$ times the edge length... I think in your answer the cirdumradius actually approaches $2$, not $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @K.defaoite Hmmm.  Let me do it again.

Comment: Distance from the center to a vertex is $\sqrt{\left(1 - \frac{1}{n+1}\right)^2 + \frac{n}{(n+1)^2}}$ which tends to $1$ as $n\to\infty$. Also, consider the triangle formed by the origin, the center and a vertex. It is right-handed and vertex-origin is the hypotenuse with length $1$, so the other two distances cannot exceed $1$.

Comment: @AdamZalcman Yes, I agree with your calculation.  I'll edit my post.  Can't figure out what I did wrong before, since I didn't write down the intermediate steps.  I think I must have misread an $n$ as $n^2$.

Comment: @saulspatz It seems we both had errors! Many thanks to Adam for his corrections.

Answer (score 3):

I think the easiest way to go about this problem is to embed the $n-1$ simplex in a plane in $\Bbb{R}^{n}$. If we do this, it is well known that we can represent the vertices of the $n-1$ simplex in $\Bbb{R}^{n}$ as simply $\{\mathbf{e}_i\}$, the unit vectors. However, one might notice that that the mean position of the vertices is
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbf{e}_i=\left(\frac{1}{n},...,\frac{1}{n}\right)$$
So it might make sense to shift our coordinates system so that the "center of mass" is the origin. That is, we take the vertices to be
$$\mathbf{v}_i=\frac{n-1}{n}\mathbf{e}_i-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j\in\{1,...,n\}\backslash\{i\}}\mathbf{e}_j$$
However, after doing this one might notice that the side lengths are
$$\Vert\mathbf{v}_i-\mathbf{v}_j\Vert=\sqrt{2\left(\frac{n-1}{n}-\frac{-1}{n}\right)^2}=\sqrt{2}$$
So we scale down by this factor and let the vertices of our simplex be
$$\mathbf{u}_i=\frac{1}{n\sqrt{2}}\left((n-1)\mathbf{e}_i-\sum_{j\in\{1,...,n\}\backslash\{i\}}\mathbf{e}_j\right)$$
Great. So now the circumradius of the $\boldsymbol{n-1}$ simplex is simply
$$R_{n-1}=\Vert\mathbf{u}_i\Vert=\frac{1}{n\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{(n-1)^2+(n-1)}$$
So the circumradius of the $n$ simplex is
$$R_n=\frac{\sqrt{n^2+n}}{(n+1)\sqrt{2}}$$
The first few terms in the sequence are
$$\{0,1/2,1/\sqrt{3},\sqrt{6}/4,\sqrt{2/5},...\}$$
We see that $R_n\to\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\text{ as }n\to\infty$.

The upshot is that the circumradius tends to $(\sqrt{2})^{-1}$ times the edge length.

Comment: Thank you very much @K.defaoite . I have a doubt: for an equilateral triangle with side length $s$ the circumradius is $s\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$. For a regular thetrahedron with edge length $s$, the circumradius is $s\frac{\sqrt{6}}{4}$. Could you please explain me why I do not see these ratio constants using your final formula?

Comment: I think there is an error here. Circumradius cannot be longer than an edge. To see this, consider the triangle formed by the origin $(0, \dots, 0)$, the center $(1/n, \dots, 1/n)$ and a vertex $(1, 0, \dots, 0)$. It is right-handed (take dot product of $(1/n, \dots, 1/n)$ and any $(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ in the simplex, i.e. such that $\sum_i x_i = 0$). Also note that vertex-to-origin line is the hypotenuse and its length is 1. Circumradius is a side in this triangle. This means that circumradius cannot be longer than $1$. Therefore, circumradius-to-edge radio cannot exceed $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: Found the error. I needed to *divide* by $\sqrt{2}$, not multiply. Thanks for the feedback, all.

Comment: @Let101 It should work now. Note that in order to get the circumradius of the $n$ simplex you actually need to plug in $n+1$ into the formula. I'll edit that into the post. **The formula for the $n$ simplex in more useful form is now in.**

Comment: @K.defaoite Thank you a lot!

Comment: @K.defaoite
Is it true that $R_n = \frac{\sqrt{n^2 + n}}{(n+1)\sqrt(2)} * a^n$, where a is the length side length and so $V_n = \frac{1}{n}\sqrt{\frac{n+1}{2^n}} * a$, where V is "volume" of tetrahedron in higher dimensions  ?? I am trying to find any answer for it for over a few hours without any success :/

Comment: @Michal Should be the other way around. The circumradius should scale linearly with the side length and the $n$ dimensional measure should scale with the $n$th power of the side length.

Comment: Ah yes, bit late here. It should be $V_n = \dots * a^n$ and $R_n = \dots * a$ :) !